# Nonlinear Pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The question I have is mostly on stability analysis but the problem is:
Consider a nonlinear pendulum. Using a linearized stability analysis, show that the inverted position is unstable. What is the exponential behavior of the angle in the neighborhood of this unstable equilibrium position.

I don't understand what `inverted position` means, what position was it in to begin with? I found [this thing](http://www.ualberta.ca/~pass/math372/linearstability.pdf) on linearized stability analysis but I'm not totally sure if that applies to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The pendulum equation of motion is given by
$$
mL^{2}\ddot{\theta} = mgL\sin\pars{\theta}\quad\imp\quad
\ddot{\theta} - {g \over L}\,\sin\pars{\theta} = 0
$$
where $m$: *mass*, $L$: *length*, $g$: *gravity acceleration*
$\ds{\approx 9.8\ {{\rm m} \over {\rm sec}^{2}}}$. $\theta$ is the angle from the vertical line where $\theta = 0$ $\pars{~\it\mbox{inverted pendulum}~}$ is the highest point and $\theta = \pi$ is the lowest point.

1. When $\theta \approx 0$, the equation of motion becomes
           $$
           \ddot{\theta} - {g \over L}\,\theta \approx 0$$
       which has solutions $\theta\pars{t} \sim \exp\pars{\pm\root{g \over l}t}$
       which renders the motion unstable.
2. When $\theta \approx \pi$, the equation of motion becomes
           $$
           \ddot{\theta} + {g \over L}\,\pars{\theta - \pi}\approx 0$$
       which has solutions
       $\theta\pars{t} - \pi \sim \exp\pars{\pm\ic\root{g \over l}t}$
       which oscillates around the lowest point $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with angular frequency}\ \root{g \over L}~}}$ and it means the motion is stable..

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "inverted position" means that the pendulum is pointing straight up.

Intuitively, we know that this is unstable since any perturbation away from perfectly vertical will cause the pendulum to swing downwards. To show this, you'll compute the linearization of the system when the pendulum is pointing straight up and you'll find that it's unstable (and probably that the distance from vertical grows exponentially).

Answer (score 0):

"Inverted Pendulum" - this means that the pendulum (system) is in it's upright position. The pendulum in its natural pendent state is stable because that position of the system falls in to a stable attractor. As it swings, up on reaching its upright position the attractor  remains no longer stable. The system parameters does receive a small control signal up on reaching the  up right position due to the presence of an attractor(weak). Lyapunov second method works perfectly fine for analyzing stability of this system.The behavior of the angle in the vicinity of the unstable equilibrium position is chaotic, since topological mismatch & Cantor set appears in this position.